# Secha ExtJs workspace and multiple pages(apps)

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I understand how to create and use multiple pages(or apps) within a workspace and build them. I am kind of confused about how do you make these multiple apps talk to each other ?

lets say I have two apps in my workspace - App1 and App2.

I can use routing and make apps talk to each other if the value is simple enough(like a user id).

What If i have to send multiple id's or data from App1 to App2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a few options available.

- URL Parameters that you parse when instantiating the second application:
  `http://example.com/app2.html?one=1`
- Anchor in the location:
  `http://example.com/app2.html#one:1`
- If the applications are hosted on the same domain, you can use something like [SessionStorage](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage) or [LocalStorage](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage) (provided they are available to the client)
- Set a cookie

Comment: is it possible to share stores across pages ?

Comment: If you create a store using the Session or Local storage proxy (depending on how long you want the data to remain on the client), then yes. Each application can load the store and have access to the data stored on the client

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove cards panels dynamically in one page without providing 2 or more pages.The sencha app is designed for single page app.