# Passing parameters in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to ExtJS. I'm working with ExtJS 5. I thought it would be an easy thing to find on google, but after a long search I didn't get a clear, understandable answer. I want to pass a parameter when navigating from one page to another, so I'm able to use the value of the parameter on the second page. I use the following method to navigate to that second page:

```
Ext.History.add('page2')
```

I have the parameter I want to send assigned to a var, so if it was possible to do it like below, I could do something like:

```
Ext.History.add('page2?parameter=' + variable);
```

Update:

I solved this problem by passing a cookie and retrieving it on the next page with

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set(cookieName, cookieValue);
```

and

```
Ext.util.Cookies.get(cookieName);
```

Comment: are you looking for the same thing as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197109/secha-extjs-workspace-and-multiple-pagesapps/30198125#30198125)?

Comment: Where is your question? Without a clear question, you can't get a clear answer...

Comment: The question is: How do I pass a parameter from one page to another? I'm trying to take information from the first page to fill the next page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var itemId = record.getData()["id"];
Ext.History.add('item&id=' + itemId); // adding items
Ext.getCmp('page2').getLayout().setActiveItem(1); // go to page
```

You can set parameters by adding it inside a `history.add()`. Take a look on 
[Senscha Ext.History](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.util.History.html).

Comment: I'm using Ext.History.add to navigate between pages. For example if a function does Ext.History.add('page1'); it will navigate to page1. The url will become www.example.com/#page1. I tried adding a parameter after page1 like Ext.History.add('page1?id=' + itemId); but that only results in the application not recognizing the url and then it will show the default/main page.

Answer (score -1):

In ExtJS 5 the router is the right way to do this if you need back button compatibility.
Please read
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/application_architecture/router.html

ExtJS apps are typically single page apps so when you go from "page" to "page" (actually just panel to panel), typically URL does not change.

As far as passing params when you open a new panel, you would just let your controller handle that OR set the param in the constructor of the new Panel.

Please paste some sample code and maybe I can provide a more precise answer.
-DB